# Javascript how to optimise this count array values function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that mimics the `array_count_values` function from php in javascript but it's not very fast. I'm wondering if there's a way to fix it?

```
function array_count_values(arr) {
    let a = [], prev;
    arr.sort();
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(1)
        } else {
            a[a.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

It just returns a simple array of numbers with the counts so like `2,1,2,1,1`. The input in this case would be numeric arrays 5-7 elements long, so for example `array_count_values([6,4,10,6,6])`

Comment: Won't be better if your result is an `object` where the `keys` are the array values and the object `values` are the number of times an element appears?

Comment: Not sorting the array will definitely help the perfs.

Comment: Not in this case since I need to sort it in order of largest first after I get the result from this function. An object is much harder to sort. You're right it is normally like that though and that's how it is in php. But in php it's easier to sort an object like that.

Comment: Sorting is a tad slower since it has a time complexity of `O(nlogn)`. It's possible to solve this in one loop.

Comment: Yes I'm sure the function doesn't need to sort. I need an array output like this though `2,1,2,1,1` and not an object.

Comment: @Hasen Please, clarify your expected output (need of sort) and that you want an array as final result in your question, or you won't get an accurate answer.

Comment: @Shidersz I did specify, check above. "It just returns a simple array of numbers with the counts so like 2,1,2,1,1." My example code returns an array of simple numbers, not an object too so I don't see how it's not clear?

Comment: @Hasen But why are the counts in that order?, to what input that output is related? Wasn't only me, a lot of assume the same that I have commented after reading what the `php` method **array_count_values()** does...

Comment: Notwithstanding OP question, I think in the JS world such a function should return a `Map<value, frequency>`.

Comment: @Shidersz Well it's similar to the php function but I was looking for an optimisation of my code here which outputs a simple array, not code with a different output. People did know what is needed though, I think it's just hard to make it output an array. Someone below commented his answer doesn't output an array like in my code does. The counts are in that order because they have not been sorted? What order should they be in?

Comment: If someone can tell me a quick way to sort an object by value then I would be happy with an object returned. But I've been unable to find a good way to do that so I prefer a simple array. For example I would need to sort `{3: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 12: 2, 14: 2}` into `{12: 2, 14: 2, 3: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}`

Comment: you can not sort an object. the order of numbers as keys as long as they could be indices of an array are ascending.

Comment: @Nina Scholz Ok so that's why it must return an array and not an object like my original code does.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the array and count each entry.

```js
function array_count_values(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((c, v) => {
    c[v] = c[v] || 0;
    c[v]++;
    return c;
  }, {})
}

var result = array_count_values([6, 4, 10, 6, 6]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is not the same as my code, it returns an object rather than an array. I just wanted an optimised version of my code.

Answer (score 3):

You could take an object for counting and omit sorting. This approach uses a single loop.

```js
function array_count_values(array) {
    var count = {},
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] in count) {
            count[array[i]]++;
        } else {
            count[array[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return Object.values(count).sort((a, b) => b - a);
}

console.log(array_count_values([6, 4, 10, 6, 6]));
```

Comment: Note this works because you have the same references in the array `[a, a]`, would it be `[{ id: a }, { id: a }]` it would not.

Comment: These all return objects, unlike my code which returns an array.

Comment: @Hasen, by returning an array, you need the sorted array as well, otherwise the counts makes no sense. do you want to get a single array with the counts? which order should it have?

Comment: At the moment I'm sorting it _after_ I get the array from this function. So it returns a single array like `1,1,2,2,1` and then I sort it to get `2,2,1,1,1`. The order is largest first.

Comment: then just add a sort to the array like `result.sort((a, b) => b - a)`.

Comment: @Hasen, you need to take the values of the object and sort them descending. please see edit.

Comment: Ok yes that works as expected, it returns an array already sorted. Unfortunately I tested it and it's not any faster than my original code..even though I have another sort() after the `array_count_values` it's still the same speed as your function. Maybe it's your object sort that slows it down?

Comment: it should be faster, because it moves the sorting part to the end of the function, but you approach is faster, because you build the result array on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 3];

function array_count_values (arr) {
  const frequencies = arr.reduce((f, v) => {
    const freq = f.get(v) || 0; 

    f.set(v, freq + 1);
    return f;
  }, new Map());

  return arr.map(v => frequencies.get(v));
}

console.log(array_count_values(arr));
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, it's the only answer that actually returns an array like my code does and like I specified. UnfortunatelyI tested it and it seems to be about the same speed as my original code. Perhaps a few ms quicker.

Comment: I initially incorrectly implement my answer. Thanks. Please note that you know the size of your input. So maybe you could try to write a really custom function without any loop at all. This implementation is very generic, it could be interesting to see how it scales compared to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a straight-forward algorithm. I've been brushing up on them lately:

```
var array_count_values = function(array) {
  let dict = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    var num = array[i];
    (dict[num]) ? dict[num]++ : dict[num] = 1;
  }
  return dict;
}

console.log(array_count_values([6, 4, 10, 6, 6]));
```

Time and space complexity is both `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how `array_count_values` works in php. This might be what you are looking for

```
function array_count_values(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (!acc[val]) {
      acc[val] = 0
    }
    acc[val] += 1
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

To return an array as required in the question

```
function array_count_values(arr) {
  return Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (!acc[val]) {
      acc[val] = 0
    }
    acc[val] += 1
    return acc
  }, {}))
}
```

Comment: This returns an object and not an array like in my example code?

Comment: My assumption was you wanted it to work like the `array_count_values` PHP function which returns an associative array. An object literal in JS is the equivalent of an associative array in PHP

Comment: No all I wanted was an optimised version of my original code which is similar to the php function but if you test it it actually returns an array, not an object. The code works fine, I just felt it could be quicker.

Comment: Then wrapping the return value in `Object.values` does what you want. Let me add that alternative

Answer (score 0):

I think the addition of a sort here is overkill, and probably the slowest part of this.

I think this will be the fastest/simplest way you can do this.

```
function array_count_values(arr) {
    let outputCounts = {};
    for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if (outputCounts[arr[i]] != undefined){
            outputCounts[arr[i]] += 1;
        } else {
            outputCounts[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return outputCounts;
}
```

The caveat here is that you're going to get an object back instead of an array as in your example.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, it needs to return an array like in my example code, not an object. Objects can be nice but hard to manipulate in some situations. In my situation an array is more useful.